# Should I remove all SKSpriteNodes and Labels when I switch from one node to another

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My iOS game has a couple of scenes. I've noticed some lag between switching scenes, and I was wondering if it might be because I'm not removing all nodes and labels from parents when I transition to another scene. Is it good practice to remove all nodes from their parent when transitioning to another scene?

Also, I've noticed that when I do remove all nodes, the transition effect is kind of ruined, as the screen goes all black during the transition.

Is it possible to delete nodes(of previous scene) after the transition to next scene?

Comment: Welcome to SO Venkat, your question is too generic..what do you mean for "removing all nodes and labels from parents?" Are you speaking about SKNode and SKLabelNode, or you mean also UILabels? Can you report some of your code to better understand what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear with my question. When I change scenes, should I call removefromParent() on the SKSpriteNodes in scene 1(before transitioning to scene 2)? I only have SKNodes in my game.

Comment: @Venkat You don't have to call removeFromParent. You have to make sure that previous scene is deallocated properly. Override deinit and see what is going on. Also, there are many things that can cause the lag ... One of the weirdest reasons, but probably  many people know about it, is wrong font name :) So check that just in case. The thing with wrong font name is that iOS will search through all fonts and that will result in noticeable lag.

Comment: I'm very new to all this, what exactly should I override deinit with?

Comment: @Venkat Just override scene's deinit and put a print statement in it to know if the scene is deallocated properly. deinit is called when the scene is about to deallocate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform the transition, the scene and its nodes will be released from memory, unless you have a [strong reference cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID52). Also, you should know that SpriteKit has its own cache system for the SKTextures, so not all memory will freed.

The lag could be caused by a lot of thing, some possibilities:

1. If you instantiate the new scene on touchesEnded (or your custom button callback closure), the lag could be caused because you're doing too much work on the initialization. This can be solved by, for example, preloading the scene with a closure that run in background and, when you have to run the transition, you already have everything loaded. An example follows:
   [image]
2. Maybe you're using assets that are too large and because they take longer to be loaded, you have the lag. You could solve this by, for example, converting images that don't need an alpha channel to .jpeg.
   Another solution would be to preload assets. A code example follows.
   [image]