# Loading sprites and lags

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

So I have a game on spritekit that has two scenes. So when I start the app I go to my firstscene, click on play button  and transfer to my gamescene. The first time I do this there is a major lag. But when I transfer from my gamescene back to firstscene then back to gamescene again the lag is gone and it works perfectly. I dont think this has to do with my sktransition from scene to scene but rather a memory load. Maybe the system needs to open up more free space, because when I place only one node in gamescene the transition to gamescene doest lag.

P.S the transition back to firstcene has no lag.

Here's the content in my gameview controller.

(Opening is the name of my firstscene)

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GoogleMobileAds
import GameKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {




        super.viewDidLoad()


        if let scene = Opening(fileNamed:"Opening") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = false
            skView.showsNodeCount = false
            skView.showsPhysics = false

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }   
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
        return true
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you searched the site for '[sprite-kit] lag' or something?  People have asked the same question over and over.

Comment: Are you using simulator?

Comment: I found the solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827022/should-i-remove-all-skspritenodes-and-labels-when-i-switch-from-one-node-to-anot/39838746#39838746